# missing method exceptions with Groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I am new to groovy. I have a code like this.

String flavor

```
HashMap config = new HashMap([ ttl: 0, url: url, appName: appName, enable: true ])
client.put("${data}.json", config)
```

From this client Map I need to iterate the values of appName and enable.
For that I used get method...  I am not sure about this.

```
def values = client.get("${data}.json");
```

while using this get method am getting following error.  Since I am new to groovy i don't know what is happening here

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.comcast.csv.haxor.SecureFirebaseRestClient.get() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [testJson.json]
>   
> Possible solutions: get(com.comcast.tvx.megahttp.utils.URL, java.lang.Class), get(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), getAt(java.lang.String), wait()

Comment: what is client and how you have initialized it ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do, but (without knowing other details) I'd put your code that way:

```
Map config = [ ttl: 0, url: url, appName: appName, enable: true ]
client[ "${data}.json" ] = config
def values = client[ "${data}.json" ]
```

assuming, that you wanted to use `getAt()` (short-cut with `[]` ) method instead of `get()`

Comment: Also probably worth calling `toString()` on the keys before using them, as otherwise you'll likely get problems further down the line

Comment: I think `client` is an instance of `com.comcast.csv.haxor.SecureFirebaseRestClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def config = [ ttl: 0, url: url, appName: appName, enable: true ]
def endpoint = "${data}.json" as String

client.put(endpoint, config)
def values = client.get(endpoint, HashMap)

def appName = values.appName
def enable = values.enable
```

I couldn't find any info on *SecureFirebaseRestClient*, so I'm guessing about how it works.